# Can anyone tell my why I'm getting the error [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode']

Tags: python, excel, smtp, attachment

I keep trying to run this code in order to send an excel sheet as an attachment on an email. I can send normal emails using smtplib but can't get the MIMEMultipart to work. I keep getting the [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'] error

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders

fromaddr = ['Email']
sendto = ['Email']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = sendto
msg['Subject'] = 'This is cool'

body = "this is the body of the text message"


msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = 'Work.xlsx'
attachment = open('/home/mark/Work.xlsx', 'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= %s' % filename)

msg.attach(part)

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('email', 'password')


text = msg.as_string()
smtpObj.sendmail(fromaddr, sendto , text)
smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.4.3 if that makes a difference

Comment: Including the entire traceback might be illuminating, but I think @Kevin is right.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
fromaddr = ['Email']
sendto = ['Email']
```

This looks a little odd to me. Shouldn't they be strings, not lists?

```
fromaddr = 'Email'
sendto = 'Email'
```

Answer (score 20):

Still I was getting an error, so I did below changes and it worked for me.

```
toaddr = ['mailid_1','mailid_2']
cc = ['mailid_3','mailid_4']
bcc = ['mailid_5','mailid_6']
subject = 'Email from Python Code'
fromaddr = 'sender_mailid'
message = "\n  !! Hello... !!"

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = ', '.join(toaddr)
msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(cc)
msg['Bcc'] = ', '.join(bcc)
msg['Subject'] = subject

s.sendmail(fromaddr, (toaddr+cc+bcc) , message)
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems bug. For to email list.  You need to handle it little differently.
The To message attribute you need as string, whereas the function for sending needs a list.
I see it pass with To attribute being list as well but outlook only first recipient is getting mail. Others though shown in To list but they never get any mails.

```
to_mail_list = ", ".join(to_mail)
msg['To'] = to_mail_list
smtp_obj.sendmail(from_mail, to_mail, msg.as_string())
```